# Tournament data modeling with MongoDB and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm developing an application with ROR, MongoDB and Mongoid.

My aplication has two models: `team` and `match`. The model `match` has two documents `away_home` and `home_team`. My question is: How do I make the relation between `teams` and `match`?

Should I use `has_and_belongs_to_many`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Emily S solution would work, but  if you intend to query a lot for the teams directly, it will be troublesome, as you're querying for the embedded documents, and you are better off having them as root documents.

There is a quite similar post on SO here [Mongoid - two fields inverses of the same foreign field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191688/mongoid-two-fields-inverses-of-the-same-foreign-field)

If that doesn't work for you, I happen to also have teams and matches :). What I do, since team ids are static in my case is I have two fields for home and away team, index them, and use them to query the teams I need. Not the best solution maybe, but it works.

Comment: I agree with this - you could also have the home and away teams be links to top-level documents in a teams collection.  It all depends on how you want to access that data.  If you'll never access data on a team outside of the context of a match, you could use an embedded document.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try having the two teams as embedded documents?

For example, you could do something like this:

```
class Match
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_one :away_team, :class_name => "Team"
  embeds_one :home_team, :class_name => "Team"
end


class Team
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embedded_in :match
end
```

then you could create the match like this:

```
> m = Match.new
> t = Team.new
> m.away_team = t
> m.away_team.name = "yankees"
> m.save
> t = Team.new
> m.home_team = t
> m.home_team.name = "blue jays"
> m.save
```

Your document would then look like this

```
> db.matches.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("503d2e123005c811cc000001"),
    "away_team" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("503d2e143005c811cc000002"),
        "name" : "yankees"
    },
    "home_team" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("503d2e303005c811cc000003"),
        "name" : "blue jays"
    }
}
```